# TigerVNC installation on CentOS 7 (as in Red Hat System Administrator's Guide )

Tags: centos, software-installation, vnc, remote-desktop

I want to install TigerVNC on my freshly installed CentOS 7 server, 
version centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.x86_64.

So besides other tutorials I've tried already, I followed the 
[Red Hat guide.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-TigerVNC#sec-starting-vncserver)
However with variable error messages depending on the tutorial I never got the service to start. The following is exactly what I did on a new installation of  CentOS 7:

```
yum install tigervnc-server
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service
vi /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service
```

initial file content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=<USER>

# Clean any existing files in /tmp/.X11-unix environment
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver %i
PIDFile=/home/<USER>/.vnc/%H%i.pid
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

file content after edit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root

# Clean any existing files in /tmp/.X11-unix environment
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver %i
PIDFile=/home/root/.vnc/%H%i.pid
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Instructions after file edit:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
su - root
vncpasswd
systemctl start vncserver@:1.service

Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status vncserver@:1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status vncserver@:1.service
● vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2018-01-03 09:00:17 UTC; 22s ago
Process: 2045 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver %i (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 2040 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i (code=exited,  status=2)

Jan 03 08:58:50 localhost vncserver[2045]: New 'localhost:1 (root)' desktop is localhost:1
Jan 03 08:58:50 localhost vncserver[2045]: Creating default startup script /root/.vnc/xstartup
Jan 03 08:58:50 localhost vncserver[2045]: Creating default config /root/.vnc/config
Jan 03 08:58:50 localhost vncserver[2045]: Starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
Jan 03 08:58:50 localhost vncserver[2045]: Log file is /root/.vnc/localhost:1.log
Jan 03 08:58:50 localhost systemd[1]: PID file /home/root/.vnc/localhost:1.pid not readable (y...art.
Jan 03 09:00:17 localhost systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 03 09:00:17 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
Jan 03 09:00:17 localhost systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:1.service entered failed state.
Jan 03 09:00:17 localhost systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Does anyone have a clue how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The path  /home/root/.vnc/ not exist

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you configured the wrong location for the PIDFile.
Try:

```
PIDFile=/root/.vnc/%H%i.pid
```